# Changing an object literal into a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, key-value

I'm trying to change an object literal key-value pairs into an array of arrays.

For example this

```js
var d = {
  rhino: 'mozilla',
  chrome: 8,
  engine: 'v8'
}

function objToArray(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var k in obj) {
    arr.push(obj[k]);
  }
  return arr;
}

var result = objToArray(d);
console.log(result)
```

Should return this
`[['rhino', 'mozilla'], ['chrome', 8], ['engine', 'v8']]`

How can I write a function to do this? Preferable without loops.

Comment: And what have you tried? And why not loops?

Comment: @Rajesh I've tried this but I know it's wrong. 
`function objToArray(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var k in obj) {
    arr.push(obj[k]);
}
return arr; 
}`
loops become hard to follow.

Comment: All you have to do is `arr.push([k, obj[k]])`. Also loops become hard because your basic are weak. If you work hard on them, it will become easy to understand loops.

Comment: @Rajesh thank you. Is there a more terse way to do it? Any hints would be helpful

Comment: I'll update Pranav's answer as he has made it wiki post. Also note, shorter code is not always better. It will compromise readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods.

#### Your approach updated

```js
var d = {
  rhino: 'mozilla',
  chrome: 8,
  engine: 'v8'
}

function objToArray(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var k in obj) {
    arr.push([k,obj[k]]);
  }
  return arr;
}

var result = objToArray(d);
console.log(result)
```

#### ES5

```js
var obj = {
  rhino: 'mozilla',
  chrome: 8,
  engine: 'v8'
};

var res = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
  return [k, obj[k]]
});

console.log(res);
```

#### ES6

```js
var obj = {
  rhino: 'mozilla',
  chrome: 8,
  engine: 'v8'
};

var res = Object.keys(obj).map(x=>[x, obj[x]]);

console.log(res);
```

**FYI :** Since object properties doesn't have any order the result array order may be changed.

Answer (score 1):

While the keys of an object have no order, I suggest to keep the order with an array for the keys and map the value with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var object = { rhino: 'mozilla', chrome: 8, engine: 'v8' }, 
    keys = ['rhino', 'chrome', 'engine'],
    result = keys.map(function (key) {
        return [key, object[key]];
    });
                      
 console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
var object = { rhino: 'mozilla', chrome: 8, engine: 'v8' }, 
    keys = ['rhino', 'chrome', 'engine'],
    result = keys.map(key => [key, object[key]]);
                      
 console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: My apologies. Missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`_.zip`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#zip) with lodash 4.

```
function objToArray(obj) {
  if(!obj || typeof obj !== 'object') {
    return false;
  }
  return _.zip(_.keys(obj), _.values(obj));
}
```

See working version: http://jsbin.com/qokisoqapu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

check this snippet

```js
var obj = {
  rhino: 'mozilla',
  chrome: 8,
  engine: 'v8'
}
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return [key, obj[key]];
});

console.log(arr);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d = {
  rhino: 'mozilla',
  chrome: 8,
  engine: 'v8'
}

function objToArray(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var k in obj) {
    var ls = [k,obj[k]];
    arr.push(ls);
  }
  return arr;
}

var result = objToArray(d);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Please explain what and why you have changed. Just putting working code is not good answer